# card-element not working with Stripe.elements() is not a function error

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, laravel-8

I am trying to make a Stripe payment method on my form in Laravel App but somehow the `card-element` fails to render with a `Stripe.elements() is not a function` on browser's console.

I here's my code (cutting irrelevant code):

```
<head>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <div class="mb-6 mx-2">
            <div id="card-element"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-2 mx-2">
            @csrf
            <input type="hidden" id="payment_method_id" name="payment_method_id" value="">
            <button type="submit" id="form_submit"> Continue to payment</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
            const stripe = Stripe("{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}");
            const elements = Stripe.elements();
            const cardElement = elements.create('card', {
            });
            cardElement.mount('#card-element');
    </script>
</body>
```

I have tried solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51766964/tab-order-broken-with-stripe-card-element-and-vue-js/51776315#51776315)

Tried to do it by adding `load` event listener as:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function (){
        const stripe = Stripe("{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}");
        const elements = Stripe.elements();
        const cardElement = elements.create('card', {
        });
        cardElement.mount('#card-element');
    });
</script>
```

but still the same error `Stripe.elements() is not a function` Here's the official [Stripe Docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements) that I am following.
Can anybody tell me what am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is it should be `stripe.elements()`, lowercase.

Comment: I was calling elements on ```Stripe``` instead of the const ```stripe```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the sample from the documentation:

```js
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx'
);
var elements = stripe.elements();
```

`elements()` is a function on an *instance* of `Stripe`. You have `Stripe.elements()` in your code capitalized, probably by accident. It should be lowercase.

Comment: Yes, I was just about to answer it myself. Just saw my console warning me about an unused ```const```, Thank you.